# SQL select all values before a value is met

Tags: sql

I have a table `results` that looks like this:

| id | rating | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | '2001-01-01' |
| 1 | 10 | '2001-02-01' |
| 1 | 8 | '2001-03-01' |
| 2 | 3 | '2001-01-01' |
| 2 | 10 | '2001-02-01' |
| 3 | 2 | '2001-01-01' |
| 3 | 5 | '2001-02-01' |
| 3 | 3 | '2001-03-01' |
| 4 | 8 | '2001-01-01' |
| 5 | 10 | '2001-01-01' |

I would like to select all the rows where `rating = 10` is reached, before or when it is reached, to get something like this:

| id | rating | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | '2001-01-01' |
| 1 | 10 | '2001-02-01' |
| 2 | 3 | '2001-01-01' |
| 2 | 10 | '2001-02-01' |
| 5 | 10 | '2001-01-01' |

What is the SQL query to do this?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.day <= (select min(t2.day)
                from t t2
                where t2.id = t.id and t2.rating = 10
               );
```

Another method uses a window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when rating = 10 then day end) over (partition by id) as day_10
      from t
     ) t
where day <= day_10;
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table t2
                   WHERE t1.id = t2.id
                     AND t1.day > t2.day
                     AND t2.rating = 10 )
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM table t3
               WHERE t1.id = t3.id
                 AND t3.rating = 10 );
```

---

```sql
WITH
cte AS ( SELECT *, SUM(rating = 10) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY day DESC) ok
         FROM table )
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ok;
```